How to find the max amount of an opportunity without using aggregate result in apex trigger?
Trigger Handler:
public class oppHandler {
    
    public static void updateoppName(List<Opportunity> oppList,Map<Id,Opportunity> mapoldOpp)
    {
        Set<Id> accIds=new Set<Id>(); // collecting all unique Ids
       
        for(Opportunity newopp:oppList)
        {
            if(mapoldOpp!=null) // after update operation
            {
               
                if(mapoldOpp.get(newopp.Id).Amount !=newopp.Amount)
                {
                   
                    accIds.add(newopp.AccountId);
                   
                }
                    
            }
            
            else
            {
                
                 accIds.add(newopp.AccountId); // after insert operation
            }
           
            
            
        }
       
        if(!accIds.isEmpty())
        {
            
            Map<Id,Decimal> mapaggAmount=new Map<Id,Decimal>(); // finding maximum amount using aggregate function
            List<AggregateResult> agOpps=[Select AccountId,MAX(Amount) maxAmount,
                                          Name from 
                                          Opportunity 
                                          where AccountId in:accIds 
                                          group by AccountId,Name 
                                         ];
            
            for(AggregateResult ag:agOpps)
            {
               
                mapaggAmount.put((Id)ag.get('AccountId'),(Decimal)ag.get('maxAmount'));
                
            }
            
            List<Opportunity> collectOpps=[Select AccountId,Name,Amount from 
                                           Opportunity where AccountId in:mapaggAmount.keySet()
                                           order by Amount DESC LIMIT 1];
            
          
            Map<Id,Opportunity> mapfindmaxAmt=new Map<Id,Opportunity>();
            
            for(Opportunity op:collectOpps)
            {
                
                if(mapaggAmount.containsKey(op.AccountId))
                {
                    
                    mapfindmaxAmt.put(op.AccountId,op);
                    
                }
                
                
            }
            
            List<Account> acctoUpdate=new List<Account>();
            for(Id accountId:mapfindmaxAmt.keySet())
            {
                
                Opportunity getoppName=mapfindmaxAmt.get(accountId);
                
                Account acc=new Account();
                acc.Id=getoppName.AccountId;
                acc.maxOpp__c=getoppName.Name;
                acc.maxOpp_Id__c=getoppName.Id;
                acctoUpdate.add(acc);
                
                
            }
            
            if(!acctoUpdate.isEmpty())
            {
                update acctoUpdate;
               
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

I'm working on a trigger where I want to find the opportunity with the maximum amount for an account. I then want to update the opportunity name and the respective opportunity ID on the account object.
Currently, I'm using the AggregateResult to identify the maximum amount of an opportunity with the help of the MAX function.
My question is, how can I find the maximum amount of an opportunity without using AggregateResult? Is there a workaround for this?

Any specific reason to not use Aggregate query?

N.B. if(!acctoUpdate.isEmpty()) is unnecessary. DML on empty lists does not burn any limits

You can achieve this by querying all opportunities related to the account and then iterating all opportunities through the loop and getting the MAX Amount of opportunities for a specific Account.
Below is the updated code:
public class oppHandler {

        public static void updateoppName(List<Opportunity> oppList, Map<Id, Opportunity> mapoldOpp) {
                Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>(); 

                for (Opportunity newopp : oppList) {
                        if (mapoldOpp != null) { // after update 
                                if (mapoldOpp.get(newopp.Id).Amount != newopp.Amount) {
                                        accIds.add(newopp.AccountId);
                                }
                        } else {
                                accIds.add(newopp.AccountId); // after insert 
                        }
                }

                if (accIds.size() > 0) {
                        Map<Id, Opportunity> mapfindmaxAmt = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
                        for (Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id, Name, AccountId, Amount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accIds ORDER BY Amount DESC]) {
                                if(opp.Amount != Null && !mapfindmaxAmt.containsKey(opp.AccountId)) {
                                    mapfindmaxAmt.put(opp.AccountId, opp);
                                }
                        }

                        List<Account> acctoUpdate = new List<Account>();
                        for (Id accountId : mapfindmaxAmt.keySet()) {
                                Opportunity getoppName = mapfindmaxAmt.get(accountId);
                                Account acc = new Account();
                                acc.Id = getoppName.AccountId;
                                acc.maxOpp__c = getoppName.Name;
                                acc.maxOpp_Id__c = getoppName.Id;
                                acctoUpdate.add(acc);
                        }

                        if (acctoUpdate.size() > 0) {
                                update acctoUpdate;
                        }
                }
        }
}


With this approach , you will blow the CPU limit if the number of records is large. This is where Aggregate queries are helpful. One question to ask here is why do we don't want to use aggregate query ?

Thank you Tushar Jadav. Now the code is working fine.

You're approaching this from the wrong direction. You can actually make this easy enough by using a subquery:
public static void updateoppName(Opportunity[] afterSave, Opportunity[] beforeSave)
  Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
  // Used as a shortcut for if checks using new ??
  Opportunity[] def = new Opportunity[0];
  for(Opportunity opportunityRecord: beforeSave ?? def) {
    accountIds.add(opportunityRecord.AccountId);
  }
  for(Opportunity opportunityRecord: afterSave ?? def) {
    accountIds.add(opportunityRecord.AccountId);
  }
  Account[] accountUpdates = new Account[0];
  for(Account accountRecord: [
    SELECT 
      maxOpp__c, 
      maxOpp_Id__c,
      (SELECT Name FROM Opportunities ORDER BY Amount DESC LIMIT 1) 
    FROM Account 
    WHERE Id = :accountIds
  ]) {
    Opportunity opportunityRecord = accountRecord.Opportunities.isEmpty() 
      ? new Opportunity()
      : accountRecord.Opportunities[0];
    // Only update records that have changed
    if(record.maxOpp_Id__c != opportunityRecord.Id || record.maxOpp__c != opportunityRecord.Name) {
      accountUpdates.add(new Account(Id=record.Id, maxOpp__c=opportunityRecord.Name, maxOpp_Id__c=opportunityRecord.Id));
    }
  }
  update accountUpdates;
}

This lets you get the extra values you're looking for, without having queries in a loop.

Thank you sfdcfox. I tried this approach also. Its working fine.

For Account and Opportunities, if you could ignore the requirement to get particular Opportunity ID and Name, you can use RollUp field on the Account as there is Master-Detail relationship. If you need quick access to the particular Opportunity from the UI, you can sort the Related List on Page Record by Amount field, so highest amount Opportunity will be at the top.
Otherwise, if RollUp summary cannot be use, the aggregate query is currently the best and most optimal took for that. However, it has it's own limits, so if you expect that the number of Opportunities will grow very fast, better scaling approach is implementing own Batch class with either Scheduled Job that runs once, maximum few times a day and calculate MAX Opportunity for all Accounts, or, most complicated, Batch framework that queues recalculation jobs and runs them when necessary in intervals (like every 30, 60 minutes).
Maybe DLRS library would be an option here, but I'm not sure if it can get the highest value record's ID and Name.

Thank you for answering my question zantaszek9. Really insightful.
